# How to delete or workaround the wrong MPN certificates from my WP dev account

Tags: windows-phone-8, mpns

I have uploaded the wrong MPN certificates to my WP dev account at https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/Account/Certificates. Is there any way to fix this issue by deleting or workaround the WRONG MPN certificates? Microsoft guys told me that there is no way to delete the added wrong MPN certificates currently and advised me to ask for help from tech forums. Pls help and advice! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My WorkAround Solution

- Go in your manifest and disable push notification. 
  WMAAppManifest.xml -> Capabilities -> ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION (uncheck)
- go in this site and make a cert, with the same CN of previous
  http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ -> download cert
- upload the cert in the store

*it is a workaround, when you disable the Push, the certification is not used.